# How to send email in internal/restricted/ highly restricted mood from Outlook in Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

I am using win32com.client library:

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.To = "xxxx@officemail.com"
message.Subject = "abcd"
message.Body = "abc xyz"
message.Send()
```

Here how to add option as `internal`/`restricted`/ `highly restricted`?

Without adding I am getting error as follows:

> com_error: (-214747260, "Operation aborted", None, None)

Comment: Do you use AIP in Outlook? What method or property exactly gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any built-in property for that.

If you use AIP add-in in Outlook you need to add a corresponding user property by using the [UserProperties.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) method. Read more about API labeling in the [Azure Information Protection (AIP) labeling, classification, and protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/aip-classification-and-protection) article. You can explore existing items and their labels using any low-level exploring tool such as MFCMAPI or OutlookSpy.

You may find the [What is Azure Information Protection?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/what-is-information-protection) page helpful.